# Binding library for Xamarin produce DLL that don't have information about classes

Tags: c#, android, dll, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am trying to add .jar to my C# Xamarin project. I use binding library, and produce .dll file. But unfortunately I don't know why my .dll have only two kind of objects:

- R
- BuildConfig

and nothing about classes like EcoGallery etc.

I add to my Xamarin project Binding Library for Android with .jar from [EcoGallery](https://github.com/falnatsheh/EcoGallery).
Then build that library, and add reference to that binding library in main project.

Now I start to using that library, so I add in my .axml

```
<us.feras.ecogallery.EcoGallery
                android:id="@+id/question_gallery"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:spacing="5px" />
```

Everything compile, project run and fragment with EcoGallery was loaded successfully. But now I wonder how to refer from C# to that question_gallery object:

So firstly I add to my fragment:

```
using US.Feras.Ecogallery;
```

But when I am trying to create object EcoGallery I have error:

> The type or namespace name 'EcoGallery' could not be found (are you
>   missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Any idea what I am doing wrong or what should I check firstly? In my .dll there are objects like EcoGallery, but I can't define object like that from my C# code.

Comment: Did you set the Build Action for your jar to *EmbeddedJar*?

Answer (score 2):

Automatic bindings work mostly just fine. **Just RESTART VS!!**

I lost way too much time for this

Comment: That worked! Once I restarted VS it became unresponsive (retried x3). Then I restarted the computer and hey presto, it builds!

Answer (score 1):

I had another thing causing the same problem. I needed to add references to certain other referenced classes (like GooglePlayServices.*).

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

If you only use automatic bindings it could be that the names are not correctly translated to C#. Read the section "Normalizing the API" in the bindings section of Xamarin: http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/java_integration_overview/binding_a_java_library_%28.jar%29/

To change the name you should add something like this to you metadata.xml file:

```
<attr path="/api/package[@name='us.feras.ecogallery']" name="managedName">EcoGallery</attr>
```